# Get total rows count of table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, prepared-statement

I want to get all rows count in my sql.

Table's first 2 columns look like that

[image]

My function looks like that

```
            $limit=2;
            $sql = "SELECT id,COUNT(*),dt,title,content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT " . $limit;
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $total, $datetime, $title, $content);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            if ($count > 0) {
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
```

Inside loop, I'm getting exact value of `$total`, but MySQL selects only 1 row - row with id number 1. (and `$count` is 1 too)

Tried this sql

`SELECT id,dt,title,content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 2`

All goes well.

Why in first case it selects only 1 row? How can I fix this issue?

for ex my table has 5 rows. I want to get 2 of them with all fields, and get all rows count (5 in this case) by one query.

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think you might want [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)...

Comment: Can you edit to include what your desired results are @epic_syntax?

Comment: @ImGreg for ex my table has 5 rows. I want to get 2 of them, and get all rows count (5 in this case) by one query.

Comment: @DaveRandom  
I said, I want to get it with one and only query. There are tons of ways with 2nd query

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `GROUP BY dt` if you want to use `COUNT(*)` (not sure why you're using it though).

EDIT

Fine, if you insist on doing it in a single call, here:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM news) as total,dt,title,content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT " . $limit;
```

Comment: getting $total=1 when I use GROUP BY dt

Answer (score 2):

Remove COUNT(*). You will only ever get 1 row if you leave it in there.

Comment: too smart, lol)). I posted this question to get solution not this "answer"

Answer (score 0):

This is likely cause by the variable $limit being set to 1, or not being set and mysql defaulting to 1. Try changing your first line to

```
$sql = "SELECT id,COUNT(*),dt,title,content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC";
```

**EDIT**

Change to:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,id,dt,title,content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT " . $limit;
```

And then use a second query with

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS( )
```

to get the number of rows that match the query

Comment: I need limit. Tried, no changes

Comment: Then you want to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS like @DaveRandom said. Check out my edit for more info.

Comment: I said, I want to get it with one and only query. There are tons of ways with 2nd query

Comment: Why not a second query? The second query only asks for something that mysql has already calculated so I don't see a performance issue.

Comment: How to use second query inside prepared statement?

Comment: I'm thinking commenting "that's not solution" on everyone trying to help you won't get you much more help. I bet you can do it in prepared statement, check out the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html and then ask if you still have questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8842/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-erik-kettenburg)

Answer (score 0):

This *totally* wreaks of a HW problem... why else besides a professor's retarded method to add complexity to a simple problem would you not want to run two queries?

anyways.... here:

```
 SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news) AS row_count, dt, title, content FROM news ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT
```